# Absence Request HRMS Oracle EBS Request SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

I am trying to retrieve the absence history for a specific person ( Approved, Pending, Rejected, Return to Correction).
I am just new to EBS and PL/SQL. I found in the net some useful sql queries but I am understanding fully there meaning.

The next request is to find the approved absence:

```
SELECT pat.name       absence_type,
       paa.date_start leave_start_date,
       paa.date_end   leave_end_date,
       paa.absence_days,
       paa.abs_information_category,
       paa.abs_information2,
       paa.abs_information3,
       paa.abs_information4
FROM   per_absence_attendances paa,
       per_absence_attendance_types pat,
       per_all_people_f papf
WHERE  paa.absence_attendance_type_id = pat.absence_attendance_type_id
       AND papf.person_id = paa.person_id
       AND Trunc (paa.date_start) BETWEEN Trunc (papf.effective_start_date) AND
                                          Trunc (papf.effective_end_date)
       -- I removed the next section
       /*AND TRUNC (p_date) BETWEEN TRUNC (paa.date_start) 
                                          AND TRUNC (NVL (paa.date_end, 
                                                          paa.date_start 
                                                         ) 
                                                    ) 
       */
       AND papf.person_id = :p_person_id;
```

Correct me if I am wrong, what I am understanding from this request is that if the start date of the absence is between the effective date of work for the employee in the table `per_all_people_f`  the his request for a leave is approved?

And there is no aspect of supervisor and assignment here?

To get the pending absence request we have to query the tables :

```
HR_API_TRANSACTIONS
HR_API_TRANSACTION_STEPS 
HR_API_TRANSACTION_VALUES
```

and,  `hr_api_transactions.status = 'Y'`.

The other status found:

```
'IR'=Return for correction
'E'=Error
```

but what does mean 'W' and 'D'?

And how can I get the rejected absence by the supervisor?

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Support account? Certainly, you should leverage the electronic technical reference manual,
http://etrm.oracle.com/pls/trm1222p/etrm_search.search. You should also look at the SQL associated with the seeded Oracle reports to obtain a sense of how to approach this.  With respect to the
"aspect of supervisor", you do have the column,
per_absence_attendances.authorising_person_id.

Comment: I don't have an Oracle Support account, I am just trying to understand the workflow by myself. I already looked into that manuel but it doesn't say much about the absence workflow. We do have the  column, per_absence_attendances.authorising_person_id.

Comment: found this useful link
 http://josephbijoy.blogspot.com/2013/02/get-leave-details-as-per-their-statuses.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use this table-   **pqh_ss_approval_history**

You will get all rejected/approved/RMA  etc actions..

Use below query to get meanings.

```
select distinct lookup_code,meaning from fnd_lookup_values where lookup_type='PQH_SS_TRANSACTION_STATUS' and language='US'
```